# Show and hide status bar + change status bar text color between view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7-statusbar

Yet another question about the iOS 7 status bar coloring and visibility... in my solution I want to have all these things:

- The status bar is to be hidden and shown (with animation) on a view controller in response to user actions (as they slide stuff around)
- When a new view controller is pushed on to the navigation controller, the color of the text in the status bar should change from black to white
- AND when the new view controller comes in, the status bar should always be shown

I'm having trouble with the 'View controller based status bar appearance' plist setting; when NO, I'm able to show and hide the status bar, but not change the color; whereas when set to YES, it's vice versa.

Comment: did you used UIStatusBarStyle enums for setting them? like     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:(UIStatusBarStyle)]

Comment: Yes. This works when the 'View controller based status bar appearance' plist setting is YES, but then `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];` stops working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with **View controller based status bar appearance to NO** in plist it would work.

For example->
Lets say in `viewcontroller1`, i have below piece of code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
}
```

And i push `viewcontroller2` from `viewcontroller1` which has below code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
}
```

with above code when tested in simulator, it perfectly animated the changes.